# How to create alert pop up in lightning when customer loses focus of a text field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Trying to go below metioned scenario

When a customer enters some text and then focuses away from the text field without saving (lose focus from the field) I need an  alert pop up displayed to confirm the save or not in lightning.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include details of your problem (screenshots, steps to reproduce etc.) alongside with any errors you get when applied your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what component(s) you are using, for example on your lightning:input fields you can define a client-side controller action for input events like `onblur`.

in your component:

```
<lightning:input name="input" aura:id="myinput" label="Enter some text" onblur="{! c.handleBlur }" />
```

in your contorller

```
handleBlur: function (cmp, event) {
    var validity = cmp.find("myinput").get("v.validity");
    console.log(validity.valid); //returns true
}
```

The documentation can be found at [lightning:input/documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation)

In your controller, you can add your validation, for example, if your field is empty, display a toast (using the [lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation))

If you are not familiar with lightning component composition, I strongly recommend you go through the [Trailhead Lightning Modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics).

Comment: I was thinking more of an **onfocusout** event

Comment: The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

Comment: Thanks  a lot glls. I have tried  but didn't work.Can you please give detail if possible.My requirement is when customer move out cursor from the edit text field , alert pop up should be displayed to ask "do you want to save or not"with Ok and No buttons.when I clicked on Ok its should be saved or else cleared the text field.

Comment: vandana, this site is not a free coding service, we are here to help address specific problems/questiosn you might have in regards to your implementation. You have to provide use the code you have and describe a specific problem. If overall you are new to lightning and development, Trailheads is your best bet.